# How to make form element share a bootstrap column with another element

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Multiple places in my code I need to position this  element (a globe glyph) directly to the right of a textbox, almost touching it. You could do this by doing the following

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="CustomTaskTitle" name="CustomTaskTitle" type="text" />
    </div>
<div class="col-md-1">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe pull-left"></span>
</div>
```

but then you waste and entire column. Any solutions?

**You will have to expand the jFiddle output window to max size to get the row layout

Heres my JFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5Rhzh/

You'll notice the glyph automatically goes beneath the textbox because there is no room in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap already has this. Its a component called input groups.
The correct way to do it  would be

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="CustomTaskTitle" name="CustomTaskTitle" type="text"  >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe pull-left"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And there you have space for another 3 columns

Comment: Wow I knew these were there and completely forgot I could use them for this problem, Thank You!!